# angularjs $resource service TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: json, angularjs, resources

I'm new to AngularJS, and it feels to me like fixing this is probably pretty simple and I'll be feeling really dumb, but I've tried looking at this/searching for hours. I know where the issue is coming from, but I'm unsure on how to fix it.

I had everything working just fine, then I made modifications on the backend to have the query call return additional data. I've tried both with the default query() method and configured a new custom method in the $resource service and played around with transformResponse.

```
.factory('apiEntry', function($resource, apiUrl) {
  return { 
   api: function(url) {
    return $resource(apiUrl + url + "/:id", { id: "@id" },
        { create: { method: "POST" }, save: { method: "PUT" },
         saveBulk: { method: "PUT", isArray: true }, queryAll: { method: "GET", 
         transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
            var data = angular.fromJson(data);
            return { data: data[0], counter: data[1], stats: data[2] }
         } }

 }
}
})
```

Then

```
$scope.dataRest = $scope.dataResource.queryAll();
```

Querying it, returning the data and resolving the promise works fine. I can populate the view with dataRest.data etc. But calling $save() or $delete() on it will give me this error.

For instance:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        item.$delete().then(function() {
            $scope.dataRest.data.splice($scope.dataRest.data.indexOf(item), 1);
        });
    }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm not sure exactly what structure of the data Angularjs expects. Currently the resource object is an object which property hold the original data. I'm not quite sure how best proceed from here. The best, I'm thinking, would be to deal with it inside Angularjs, if that's possible. I could also try to reformat it on the backend before returning the response, or obtaining it via a separate API call. I hope I'm making some sense, I'm new to this and so far have been able to solve my issues by testing or searching around.

Comment: Could you show how you define save and delete in your factory? And how look your server POST/PUL route

Comment: Added more of factory in post. I've been looking at Restangular over the past day and may convert over completely, but would still be nice to know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your factory I saw few methods but none of them is named `delete`? I haven't yet used the `$` operator so maybe you are correct when doing this. I will paste an example of my code that works.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('API')
        .factory('Factory', function ($resource) {
            return $resource("/REST ROUTE", {},
                {                   
                    save: {
                        method: "POST",
                        cache: true,
                        isArray: false
                    }
                }
            );
        });
})();
```

I always try to separate the api into small parts, so then you have to inject a factory into the controller and use it like this

```
$scope.Function = function(){
    Factory.save({user:user});
}
```

If you want to add more functionality I would suggest to do it in controller function or if you need it in few places, then I was only returning function from factory but haven't combining it with some operations on REST data, but maybe you could just inject one factory into another?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and attempt to help! I believe $delete(), $save(), $get() of the $resource service will just just default settings if not defined. They were working fine with the resource object before the data returned by backend was changed, so believe the issue lies there within. Breaking it up would probably make testing easier, what's cleaner is probably not something I should worry about at this stage hehe. Switched to Restangular for the moment, as it seems to be superior, where I'm facing a new issue instead...